# how to convert asp.net app to a jquery (clientside/ html5) model

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I want to move to the more modern web development techniques using html5, jquery instead of the classic asp.net web forms (post backs) method.

in particular, how do you trigger events server side?

for example: how would you get a simple login form to function where sql membership provider is used on top of a web form with 2 text boxes (username/ password) and a login button?

I have a working login with `<asp:button ...>` and textboxes with postback. I want to replace the UI controls with html5

```
<input autofocus name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
```

at the heart of the problem how do I convert the .net page to html while being able to get the data to the server for validation and authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I convert the .net page to html

Your ASP.NET webforms projects always rendered HTML to the client anyway. It sounds like what you want to is stop using those server controls (`<asp:TextBox`) and instead just use their HTML equivalent `<input type="text"`. Note that when you use `TextBox` it is rendered as `input type="text"` so using the server control isn't really a barrier in what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to move to a more "modern" development technique, then you should is to move away from WebForms and instead start using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

However, there is nothing stopping you from using your current login form and just ajax posting the data to your server to achieve that "no post-back" flow.

Comment: what if i wanted to move to a new UI based on html5 but wanted to wire up my .net backend functionality already existing... like login? add/eddit/delete users.... basicaly all the sql interactions

Comment: for example I want to replace my admin pages with an outof the box template such as http://indeziner.com/resources/freebies/free-css-templates/free-htmlcss-jquery-admin-panel-inadmin/

Comment: You can actually use UpdatePanels to not refresh the entire screen on post-back and just keep your existing functionality... but I'm not a big fan of those. Otherwise you need have something to process your Ajax posts. IMO it's easier in MVC.

Comment: Webforms is not a barrier in updating your UI. My webforms project is also partially a MVC project and is "HTML5". Your question is a little vague as to what the actual problem is.

Comment: got a link or example of how to take new html and use update panels to link the ui to my existing codebehind methods?

Comment: UpdatePanels are just more .NET server controls that disassociate you from the actual html/javascript it takes to make these things happen. It gets the job done, but IMO it's better to know how to do it without relying on their tools.